# turboprop thrust relative to the jet's propulsion

Tags: turboprop

What is the thrust ratio in a turboprop between propeller and its jet exhaust, and is the jet exhaust necessary for flight? Once the turbines are spinning, it seems the exhaust is waste product. This would be inefficient and could be used for more power. Is this so?